# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader"

Tags: jersey, weblogic12c, hk2

I am trying to override the Jersey (and dependency) libraries(v2.21) available in WebLogic 12.2.1 with application packaged ones which has Jersey v2.25.1. But end up with below:

A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are

1. > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader
2. > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to create a Proxy for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse in scope org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped an error occured while creating the proxy
3. > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.abc.xyz.JerseySampleProvider.MyProvider errors were found
4. > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.abc.xyz.JerseySampleProvider.MyProvider

Tried other versions of Jersey like 2.19 as well. Same result. Any help would be appreciated.I also came across similar reported issues in this forum but did not see a solution

XML as below

```
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
            <!-- hk2 providers -->
            <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.jvnet.tiger_types.*</package-name>

            <!-- apis -->
            <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>

             <!-- java assist -->
            <package-name>javaassist.*</package-name>

            <!-- aop repackaged -->
            <package-name>org.aopalliance.*</package-name>

            <!-- guava -->
            <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>

            <!-- jersey2 providers -->
            <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name>
            <package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>

            <!-- Jackson providers -->
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>

            <!--Others-->
            <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
          <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>

    </prefer-application-packages>
    <prefer-application-resources>
        <!-- hk2 -->
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>org.jvnet.tiger_types.*</resource-name>

        <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate</resource-name>


        <!-- Jersey -->
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>jersey.repackaged.*</resource-name>



    </prefer-application-resources>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?